# Where can I find full license agreement for f sharp language?

Tags: f#

What kind of OSI approved license does the F# language use and where can I find the full license agreement for the F# language?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/ is the official GitHub repo for the F# language. Its License.txt file, found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/License.txt), is the license usually known as the "MIT License", which is one of the most common (and [OSI-approved](https://opensource.org/licenses)) open-source licenses.